# Joomla - Custom Properties : How to assign Articles to specific Authors

Tags: joomla3.0

Hi receive the below error message when I click on one of the author [here](http://csvr.org.za/publications/publications-by-author) from customer properties Module.

[screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d12qq.png)

How do I make selection??

Answer (score 0):

Its not an error, just its not getting the right link for the search. I think you have to just link author link to a tag link at the end. Like

```
http://csvr.org.za/component/customproperties/tag/176

instead of

http://csvr.org.za/component/customproperties/tag/publications%20by%20author-Dix-Peek%20D%20?Itemid=2
```

Lets use the that author id, it will work